# SSL on localhost issue

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I have issue. I can't set SSL on localhost. With this settings i cant reach bitwarden or postgresql with my browser. I can't see where could be the problem

```
services:
  proxy:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    depends_on:
      - bitwarden


  bitwarden:
    image: bitwardenrs/server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8002:82"                   #BITWARDEN ODPALA SIE LOKALNIE, BEZ PRZESZKOD
    volumes:
      - ./bw-data:/data
    environment:
      WEBSOCKET_ENABLED: 'true'
      SIGNUPS_ALLOWED: 'true'
      DATABASE_URL: 'postgresql://postgres:qwerty@db:5432/bitwarden'
    networks:
      - postgresql

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "qwerty"
    volumes:
     - /var/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    expose:
     - "5432"
    networks:
     - postgresql


  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "Enigma_rekrutacja@proton.me"
     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "qwerty"
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
     - postgresql

networks:
  postgresql:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://bitwarden;
    }
}
```

This is my nginx.conf file

I generate token with mkcert, but its not working.

Additionaly I can say without nginx service in docker-compose file everything working fine, but I don't know where is the issue with SSL

Comment: *"but its not working"* - this error description is too broad to help you. Please explain  your test setup and the exact errors you get.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Actually i changed proxy_pass to localhost and i got 502 Bad Gateway, but now with correct SSL